# How to store the returned record of the results of a Neo4J query in Python?

Tags: python, database, graph, neo4j, record

I have connected to the Neo4J graph database using Python, and want to store the returned results of a query under an object name (e.g. 'df'), but for some reason when I simply print the output, Python prints every match for the given query, but if I try and store it under an object and call that object name, it only returns a single match. For example, if I run the following (I have to anonymise certain strings and names due to confidentiality):

```
query_object = "x"
query = """MATCH (n {name:""" + "'" + query_object + "'" """}) RETURN n"""
edge_query = "MATCH (n {name:""" + "'" + query_object + "'" """})<-[r]-(y) RETURN y.name, n.value"""
with graphDB_Driver.session() as graphDB_Session:
        graphDB_Session.run(query)
        nodes = graphDB_Session.run(edge_query)
        for node in nodes:
            print(node)
```

I get:

```
<Record y.name='a' n.value=None>
<Record y.name='b' n.value=None>
<Record y.name='c' n.value=None>
<Record y.name='d' n.value=None>
```

However if I run:

```
with graphDB_Driver.session() as graphDB_Session:
        graphDB_Session.run(query)
        nodes = graphDB_Session.run(edge_query)
        for x in nodes:
            df = node
df
```

Calling df in this case would just return:

```
<Record y.name='d' n.value=None>
```

Can someone please explain to be why this is the case and if so how do I store the entire returned set of results under an object as it is crucial to a task I am currently occupied on?

Comment: I just realised that the second chunk of code that runs the graph database states 'for x in nodes'. This is a mistake, assume that it states 'for node in nodes'.

Comment: I'm not a Pythonista, but if `df` is **not** indented **within** the for-loop, I assume `df` would then refer to the last value it was assigned to.
`df` should be an array instead, and `df = node` should be replaced with `df.append(node)`

Comment: Thanks for your comment; the issue I'm having is that 'node' is a 'Record' object which doesn't seem to be versatile whatsoever when it comes to functions that can be executed on it. So I ran df.append(node) and I got the error: 'Record' object has no attribute 'append'.

Comment: I'm not following, can you share the code where df is declared?
I thought that sth like: 
```
df = []
for node in nodes:
    df.append(node)
df
```
would work (or trigger an error different from what you describe at least). Doesn't it?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to call df as an empty list prior. It's worked; thank you so much!!

Comment: answer posted, then :)

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```py
with graphDB_Driver.session() as graphDB_Session:
        graphDB_Session.run(query)
        nodes = graphDB_Session.run(edge_query)
        df = []
        for x in nodes:
            df.append(node)
df
```

should work.